# Data validation library in Python and user defined rules

Tags: python, library, csv, validation, rules-engine

I'm starting a solution that matches data rows (importing a csv file initially) from created rules. It would be like an Excel filter solution with some specific options for date and number formats.
But my intended output is a list of matches for these created rules, then those results would be made available for a notification system.

I'm wondering if there is some python library/solution that already does this or something half-through.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/) can do a lot of the work for you and is well worth looking at.

- Reading .csv files, (also .xlsx & others)
- Format conversions for date & value columns
- Filtering

Are all available.

Comment: You're right! Thanks! Pandas should suffice all my filtering needs.

Answer (score 2):

Python's [built in CSV support](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) lets you import a CSV file and manipulate it.

You can do this as rows to iterate over (and filter):

```
import csv

def filter_file(filename: str):
  with open(filename, newline='') as csvfile:
    spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=' ', quotechar='|')

    return [
      row
      for row in spamreader
      if row[2] != "skipme"
    ]
```

Or as a list of dictionaries, to make lookups easier via column headers:

```
import csv

def filter_file(filename: str):
  with open(filename, newline='') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)

    return [
      row
      for row in spamreader
      if row["should_skip"] != "skipme"
    ]
```